# Split a long text into multiple cells in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a long text string which looks like this: (213412=a)(223412=b)(512231=c)...

I want to split this into multiple cells sitting below each other where each cell gets a string of the same size. Maybe 6 of those character bits in brackets each. How can I accomplish this?

I tried the MID formula which is generally doing what I want, however I cant seem to expand it with autofill

Answer (score 1):

Optionally, you can use this function:

`=LEFT((TEXTSPLIT(A1,,"(",TRUE,1,)),6)`

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

##### Either: Text into columns

- Text -> Text in columns with "(" or ")"
- then copy the first row with all of the new columns and special paste it with a check at "transposed" into rows
- then replace the other brackets.

##### Or: Replace split with line wrap

If the above leads to too many columns:

- put the string in a text file opened in a RegEx editor like Notepad++ or the like
- RegEx replace ")(" with a line wrap "\n"
- free it from the last brackets
- paste it in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=MID($A$1,FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE($A$1,"(","#",ROW(A1)))+1,6)
```

[image]